# Why do my volumes sometime not get mounted in my Docker container when using fig?

Tags: docker, fig

I'm seeing a strange problem in a Docker/Fig environment. My hypothesis is that it's due to a delay in mounting volumes to containers, but I'm not sure how to confirm that.

I have a container with the following:

### Dockerfile

```
FROM busybox
MAINTAINER Dan Rumney <email>

ADD loadsnapshot.sh /loadsnapshot.sh
RUN ["chmod", "u+x", "/loadsnapshot.sh"]

VOLUME ["/snapshot"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/loadsnapshot.sh"]
```

### loadsnapshot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$( ls -A /snapshot)" ]; then
  echo "Loading snapshot..."
  # Do stuff
else
  echo "No snapshot to load"
fi
```

In my fig.yml file I have:

```
pdsvol:
 image: busybox
 volumes:
 - "/opt/alfresco/alf_data"
 - "/data"
 - "/mysqlbackup"
 - "/ldapbackup"
loader:
 image: "docker.myregistry.com/snapshot.loader:3.5.0"
 volumes_from: 
 - pdsvol
 volumes:
 - "/opt/snapshots/my-data/:/snapshot/"
```

The goal here (which may be obvious) is to start up a data container (`pdsvol`) and then populate it with some data that's running on my machine. `pdsvol` is then shared by a bunch of other containers.

The way I run this is to call

```
fig up pdsvol
```

and then

```
fig run --rm loader
```

What I expect to see is

```
builder@beast:/opt/docker-vm$ fig run --rm loader
Loading snapshot...
... stuff ...
Removing dockervm_loader_run_1...
```

and, sometimes I do. However, sometimes I see:

```
builder@beast:/opt/docker-vm$ fig run --rm loader
No snapshot to load
Removing dockervm_loader_run_1...
```

I can run `fig run --rm loader` over and over and I will get one of the two outcomes.

My working theory was that there was some delay in mounting the volume and sometimes it happens before the `ENTRYPOINT` script is run and sometimes after. However, if I run:

```
 docker run --rm -v /opt/snapshots/my-data/:/snapshot/ busybox ls -A /snapshot
```

I consistently see the files I'm expecting... so this goes against that theory.

I know I could hack at `loadsnapshot.sh` and put in a delay and see if that helps, but I'd rather understand what's going on than kludge a fix.

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on here?

BTW: the host system is Linux, so we are using native containers here.

### Update

I tried putting a 2s delay at the top of `loadsnapshot.sh`, but it did not help.

### Update 2

I added some logging to fig to dump the configuration that is used to create the container and in every instance (fail or no), it's the same:

```
{
 'Env': None, 
 'Hostname': None, 
 'Entrypoint': None, 
 'Dns': None, 
 'Memory': 0, 
 'OpenStdin': True, 
 'User': None, 
 'CpuShares': None, 
 'AttachStdout': True, 
 'NetworkDisabled': False, 
 'WorkingDir': None, 
 'Cmd': None, 
 'StdinOnce': True, 
 'AttachStdin': True, 
 'Volumes': {u'/snapshot/': {}}, 
 'MemorySwap': 0, 
 'VolumesFrom': None, 
 'Tty': True, 
 'AttachStderr': True, 
 'Domainname': None, 
 'Image': 'docker.myregistry.com/snapshot.loader:3.5.0', 
 'ExposedPorts': None
}
```

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/443 to track this; I think it's actually a bug in `fig`

Comment: Met the same problem...

Comment: Seems this may be fixed in Docker 1.3

Comment: I'm using Docker 1.3 (build c78088f) and Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.3.0 (Git commit: deafc19) and it only mounts the volume at the very first time I ran `fig up`. Once restarted boot2docker, this issue comes again and again.

Comment: Are you working on VM ?  i saw similar problems on VM

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue with Docker 1.4.0/Fig 1.0.1.

Rolling back to ***Docker 1.3.1*** fixed the issue for me.

It still appears to be an open issue affecting many folks.

Although [#443](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/443) is closed, there are related open issues:

- [**Issue #622**: Since docker 1.3.0 / fig 1.0.0 volumes are not mounted when fig up'ing existing containers](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/622)
- [**Issue #723**: File volumes are broken for docker 1.4.0](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/723)
- [**Issue #443**: Local directories periodically fail to be mounted.](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/443)
- [**Pull Request #711**: Fix volumes on recreate #711](https://github.com/docker/fig/pull/711)

Comment: The new pull request is https://github.com/docker/fig/pull/858 which should address some of these issues