# docker mysql persistent storage

Tags: docker, fig, dockerfile

I have this app trying to orchestrate using docker + fig which works great for the first day of trying. It uses a data container where I want to persist my database files and a redis + mysql container(s) used by the app.

Once booted up the mysql container looks inside `/var/lib/mysql` for data files and, if none found, it creates the default sb which I can then populate and the files are created and also persisted in my data volume.

While I'm learning fig I had to do a `fig rm --force mysql` which deleted my mysql container. I did this without fear knowing that my data is safe on the data container. Running a `ls` on my host shows the mysql files still intact.

The problem occurs when I run `fig up` again which creates the mysql container again. Even though I have the same volumes shared and my old mysql files are still present this new container creates a new database as if the volume shared was empty. This only occurs if I `rm` the container and not if I close fig and bring it back up.

Here's my fig file if it helps:

`data:
  image: ubuntu:12.04
  volumes:
    - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
redis:
  image: redis:latest
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
   - 3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: *****
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
  volumes_from:
    - data
web:
  build: .
  dns: 8.8.8.8
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  environment:
    - DEBUG=True
    - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - data
    - mysql
    - redis`

Any ideas why the new mysql container won't use the existing files.?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `fig` but will be looking into it as the simplistic syntax in your post looks pretty great. Every day I spend a couple more hours expanding my knowledge about Docker and rewire my brain as to what is possible. For about 3 weeks now I have been running a stateless data container for my MySQL instances. This has been working great with no issues.

If the content ***inside*** `/var/lib/mysql` does not exist when the container starts, then a script installs the needed database files. The script checks to see if the initial database files exist not just the `/var/lib/mysql` path.

```
if [[ ! -f $VOLUME_HOME/ibdata1 ]]; then
    echo "=> An empty or uninitialized MySQL volume is detected in $VOLUME_HOME"
    echo "=> Installing MySQL ..."

else
    echo "=> Using an existing volume of MySQL"
fi
```

Here is a direct [link to a MySQL repo](https://github.com/htmlgraphic/Docker/blob/master/Docker/MySQL/5.5/run.sh) I am continuing to enhance

Comment: The files exist when mysql container boots up because docker mounts the volume first which has the required files. I even tried with killing all containers and then firing `fig up` again and it finds the files. Only when I rm the mysql container it does that. I would assume a permission error but I can't find any error relating to that...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, see this related question which has links to relevant fig/docker issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27562669/204706

Apparently the situation is improved with docker 1.4.1, so you should try using that version if you aren't already.

Comment: Switched over from fig to pure vagrant because of that bug which makes the whole setup very unreliable. I am using 1.4.1 by the way.